# Swift displaying different images when cell is tapped

Tags: swift

I can not believe that I'm stuck on this, I have tableview with cells named Bolognese, Milanese and Pizza from array, so it's just one tableview with another detailviewcontroller where UIImage is located. I want when i click on cell Bolognese to display picture of bolognese in UIImageView in in detailVC. Having problems in detailVC, I forgot how to display image from that array in detailVC. I'm ashamed of myself :). `var array2 = ["1","2","3"]` - those are pointers to images in imagexcassets Thank you.

Tableviewcontroller

```
class Hello: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var array = ["Bolognese","Milagnese","Pizza"]
var array2 = ["1","2","3"]

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return array.count
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.array[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.array2 = self.array

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let driver = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

    var whatToPass = self.array2
    driver.reciever = whatToPass
}
```

DetailViewController

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {



@IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView!

var reciever = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    self.picture.image = UIImage(named:receiver)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: What you want to do actually?

Comment: when clicked on cell bolognese to display picture of food bolognese in one uiimage in detailVC, when i click on pizza cell, to display image pizza in detailVC in same uiimage.

Comment: You want to display the image named "1" when "Bolognese" is selected, "2" when "Milagnese" is selected, and "3" when "Pizza" is selected?

Comment: yes, i want to do that in ONE uiimage in detailVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `receiver` in the destination to be a `String`:

```
var receiver = ""
```

Then in `prepareForSegue`, get the `indexPath` of the selected row and select the image name from `array2` using `indexPath.row` as the index:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let driver = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        driver.reciever = self.array2[indexPath.row]          
    }        
}
```

Then your code in `viewDidLoad` in your destination view controller will load up the proper image:

```
self.picture.image = UIImage(named:receiver)
```

Comment: Get rid of your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.  It is overwriting your `array2`.

Comment: it works, thank you a lot, and maybe you know with did select method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  When using `prepareForSegue`, you don't need the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.  It is called after `prepareForSegue` if you've wired the segue from your prototype cell in the Storyboard, so it isn't useful anyway because it is called too late.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please accept my answer when you get a chance.